# Java serverlet parse JSON data

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

I want to post JSON object from JavaScript to java serverlet.
I used the following javaScript code :

```
var a = {};
function SaveInfo(c)
{
    document.getElementById("saveButton").className = "savebutton";
    document.getElementById("cancelButton").className = "cancebutton";
    var z=  $(c).parent().parent().attr('id');
    a[z] = c.value;
}
$("#saveButton").click(function(e){
   if(  document.getElementById("saveButton").className=="savebutton")
       $.ajax({
           url: "../../update",
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: JSON.stringify(a),
           contentType: 'application/json',
           mimeType: 'application/json',
           success: function (data) {
               consol.log(data);
           },
           error:function(data,status,er) {
               alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
           }
      });
});
```

and following java code :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
    JSONObject jObj;
    jObj = new JSONObject(req.getParameter("mydata")); // this parses the json
    Iterator it = jObj.keys();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        String key = (String)it.next(); // get key
        Object o = jObj.get(key); // get value
       // store in session
    }
}
```

JSON is successfully received.
Problem is there is no constructor for :

```
jObj = new JSONObject(req.getParameter("mydata"));
```

I want to read both values and keys passed via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose you can simply use a form, simply parse it like:

```
    Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();

    for(Entry<String, String[]> e : map.entrySet()){
        response.getWriter().write(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()[0] + "\n");
    }
```

Use json when you want to send an object or a complex data array etc.

Hope that completes your work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(req.getParameter("mydata").toString());
```